# Split line by +-*/() (as delimeters) without omitting them in python

Tags: python, regex

Good day.

I'm trying to split (tokenize) a string like

`(22+33)* 44 / 300`

and get output like

`['(','22','+','33',')','*','44','/','300']`

so far I tried to use

```
infix = input("Enter the infix notation : ")
infix = re.split(r'[+-/*()]', infix)
```

but it omits delimiters and creates '' elements at list.

Comment: Try using ```regex``` to evaluate order of operations, then use ```str.partition()``` to create your three part tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting the string on delimiters, I recommend just searching for the tokens.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|[-+/*()]', infix)
['(', '22', '+', '33', ')', '*', '44', '/', '300']
```

Comment: That worked just fine, thank you! Some day I'll do my best to learn re -_-

Comment: your regex is wrong. `+-/` inside characater class works differently(`-` acts as a range operator). Your regex would be `[+\-/*()]` or `[-+/*()]` or `[+/*()-]` . I'm sure, this comment would got an upvote :-)

Comment: This regex would find also the dot in this `(22+33)* 44.50 / 300` string because dot lies in that range(from `+` to `/`). How i know this info? Ans: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 6):

[re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

```
infix = input("Enter the infix notation : ")
infix = re.split(r'([+-/*()])', infix)
```

Comment: Yes. You just need to use a capturing group to retain the matched items.

Comment: it returns empty items also.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=\+|-|\/|\*|\(|\)|\b\d+\b)
```

Try this.

use `y= re.sub(r"(?=\+|-|\/|\*|\(|\)|\b\d+\b)","\n",x)`

`print y.split("\n")`

.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kK4cB5/1